# SQL Server function to convert strings from one charset to another?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, character-encoding

I am looking for a function that changes the input character set, e.g. Japanese, to some other character set, e.g. UTF-8.

What SQL function I can use?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there is no such function as builtin. But to achieve this you can use collation settings.

Comment: To Get Current Collation `SELECT DATABASEPROPERTYEX('DBName', 'Collation') SQLCollation;`

Comment: Isn't it strange there is no such a function?

Comment: I dont think its a strange,there is a systematic way to achieve this in sql server.SInce its related to collation,its column/db/server wide  property and you simply cant change it otherwise it will affect the data stored in that column/db/server